# How to invoke Python methods using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dispatch

I'm trying to create a list (or dictionary) of methods that transform data. For example, I have data like below:

```
data = [
{'Result': 1, 'Reason1': False, 'Reason2': 1},
{'Result': 0, 'Reason1': False, 'Reason2':'haha'},
{'Result': 0, 'Reason1': True, 'Reason2': 'hehe'},
{'Result': 0, 'Reason1': True, 'Reason2': 0},
]


def rule_1(datum):
    modified_datum = datum
    if datum['Reason1']:
        modified_datum['Result'] = 1 # always set 'Result' to 1 whenever 'Reason1' is True
    else:
        modified_datum['Result'] = 1 # always set 'Result' to 0 whenever 'Reason1' is False
    return modified_datum


def rule_2(datum):
    modified_datum = datum
    if type(datum['Reason2']) is str:
        modified_datum['Result'] = 1 # always set 'Result' to 1 whenever 'Reason2' is of type 'str'
    elif type(datum['Reason2']) is int:
        modified_datum['Result'] = 2 # always set 'Result' to 2 whenever 'Reason2' is of type 'int'
    else:
        modified_datum['Result'] = 0
    return modified_datum


# There can be 'rule_3', 'rule_4' and so on... Also, these rules may have different method signatures (that is, they may take in more than one input parameter)
rule_book = [rule_2, rule_1] # I want to apply rule_2 first and then rule_1

processed_data = []
for datum in data:
    for rule in rule_book:
        # Like someone mentioned here, the line below works, but what if I want to have different number of input parameters for rule_3, rule_4 etc.?
        # processed_data.append(rule(datum))
```

I think [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7435/108356) on Stack Overflow comes quite close to what I'm trying to do, but I'd like to learn from people who are experienced with Python on how to best handle it. I tagged this post with 'dispatch', which I think is the term it is called for what I'm trying to achieve(?) Thank you in advanced for your help and suggestions!

Comment: sorry i didn't get the question, so you want to pass processed_data to all the functions in rule_book?

Comment: @alec Sorry that my question was confusing. I wanted to pass individual `dict` items in `data` to each rule in the `rule_book`. Then capture them (by appending) back into `processed_data`. But that storing things back in `processed_data` is not the main point of my question. My main question is more about how to apply/run/invoke different rule methods (possibly having **varying signatures/input parameters**) to single piece of `data` (that is, `datum`). Hope this is clearer...

Comment: Is `processed_data.append(rule(datum))` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Idlehands yes. I want to know how to dispatch/invoke different rules in the `rule` to a piece of data (`datum`). Then store the results back in a list like `processed_data` (but that storing part is secondary and I'm not that worried about it). Thank you.

Comment: It'll be difficult to iterate through `rule_book` and apply the `rule`s if you intend to have different param setups between the rules.  One way you might want to do it is using `*args` or `**kwargs` across your `rules` so you just always pass the same set of params in, but only use the relevant ones for each `rule`.

Comment: @Idlehands Actually, you're right! `processed_data.append(rule(datum))` works, but what if I want `rule_3` with, say, 2 input parameters? How do I handle that in Pythonic way? Thank you!

Comment: @Idlehands Could you please show an example of how I might use `*args` or `**kwargs`? I'm not that advanced in my Python knowledge to see what you're alluding to. Thank you...

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3#using-*args-and-**kwargs-in-function-calls) is what you are looking for

Comment: Totally unrelated but this  `modified_datum = datum`  will not works as you obviously expect - it doesn't make a copy of `datum` but makes both names point to the same object. Check this for more details; https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you're pretty close.  All you need to do is call `rule` while you iterate through.

In regards to handling varying length of params, you might opt to make use of `*args` and `**kwargs` in your rules.  Here's a quick example:

```
def rule1(*args, **kwargs):
    # Handling of non-keyword params passed in, if any
    if args:
        for arg in args:
            print(f'{arg} is type {type(arg)}')
    # if kwargs is not necessary if you don't intend to handle keyword params

def rule2(*args, **kwargs):
    # if args is not necessary if you don't intend to handle non-keyword params

    # handling of keyword params passed in, if any
    if kwargs:
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            print(f'Keyword arg {k} has value {v}')

rule_book = [rule2, rule1]
for rule in rule_book:
    # iterate through the rule_book with the same amount of args and kwargs
    rule('I am a string', 123, ('This', 'is', 'Tuple'), my_list=[0, 1, 2], my_dict={'A': 0, 'B': 1})
```

**Result:**

```
Keyword arg my_list has value [0, 1, 2]
Keyword arg my_dict has value {'A': 0, 'B': 1}
I am a string is type <class 'str'>
123 is type <class 'int'>
('This', 'is', 'Tuple') is type <class 'tuple'>
```

The key take away is keep the params consistent between your rules, once everything is passed in, just get the relevant object and make use of it:

```
def rule3(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, tuple):
                # if there's a tuple presented, reverse each of the inner items
                print([a[::-1] for a in arg])

 # ['sihT', 'si', 'elpuT']
```

With the way you have structured your code, I'm confident you should be able to understand and apply this to your own.

Comment: thank you SO MUCH! This is what I'm looking for. :) I came here looking for some advanced solution like here [http://drunkenpython.org/tag/dispatcher.html], but got a much simpler solution from you, which is perfect. :)

Comment: You're too welcome.  Happy coding! If you know you'll *always* be passing in `datum` across the board, you can even put `datum` as a static param in each rule (`def rule1(datum, *args, **kwargs):`) to avoid duplicating your handling.  But ONLY if `datum` will ALWAYS be in the rules.